# Why is this CSG Library subtract function leaving behind vertices?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, csg

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/praeclarum/Csg) CSG library to subtract two solids. I chose this particular library in order to work with the .NET Framework 4.5 dependency of my project. **My goal is to be able to successfully use boolean operations on two concave solids.** However, when I subtract two solids, the function leaves behind some of the vertices of the subtracting shape.

Below is an example of what the subtracted image should look like, rendered in 3d:
[Correct Solid Subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opnvO.png)

Instead, the function yields something like this:
[Failed Solid Subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b11L.png)

You can see that some of the vertices have been left above the subtracted solid, which causes issues in rendering, and in further operations. I've opened a GitHub issue on the repository [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/Csg/issues/9), and I've also created a failing unit test using `NUnit.Framework`, which reads points from a `.json` file (contents below):

```
[Test]
        public void CoplanarConcave ()
        {
            using StreamReader r = new StreamReader ("TestCase.json");
            string json = r.ReadToEnd ();
            List<List<List<double>>> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<double>>>> (json);
            var vectorList = items.Select (doublesList =>
                doublesList.Select (doubles => new Vector3D (doubles[0], doubles[1], doubles[2])).ToList ()).ToList ();
                
            var texture = new Vector2D (0, 0);
            var vertices = vectorList.Select (vertex => vertex.Select (vector => new Vertex (vector, texture)).ToList ())
                .ToList ();
            var polyArray = vertices.Select (vertex => new Polygon (vertex)).ToList ();
            
            var solid = Solid.FromPolygons (polyArray);
            var testSolid = solid.Translate (0, 0, 10);

            var result = solid.Substract (testSolid);
            var badPolygons =
                result.Polygons.Where (polygon => polygon.Vertices.Any (vertex => vertex.Pos.Z >= 217.125));
            Assert.IsEmpty (badPolygons);
        }
```

```
[[[744.585, 734.575, 97.125],
[1062.208, 734.575, 97.125],
[1062.208, 276.028, 97.125],
[889.654, 276.028, 97.125],
[889.654, 504.099, 97.125],
[744.585, 504.099, 97.125]],

[[744.585, 734.575, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 734.575, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 734.575, 97.125],
[744.585, 734.575, 97.125]],

[[1062.208, 734.575, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 276.028, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 276.028, 97.125],
[1062.208, 734.575, 97.125]],

[[1062.208, 276.028, 1297.125],
[889.654, 276.028, 1297.125],
[889.654, 276.028, 97.125],
[1062.208, 276.028, 97.125]],

[[889.654, 276.028, 1297.125],
[889.654, 504.099, 1297.125],
[889.654, 504.099, 97.125],
[889.654, 276.028, 97.125]],

[[889.654, 504.099, 1297.125],
[744.585, 504.099, 1297.125],
[744.585, 504.099, 97.125],
[889.654, 504.099, 97.125]],
    
[[744.585, 504.099, 1297.125],
[744.585, 734.575, 1297.125],
[744.585, 734.575, 97.125],
[744.585, 504.099, 97.125]],

[[744.585, 734.575, 1297.125],
[744.585, 504.099, 1297.125],
[889.654, 504.099, 1297.125],
[889.654, 276.028, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 276.028, 1297.125],
[1062.208, 734.575, 1297.125]]]
```

**What is the issue here? Is there a better solid geometry library that I could be using?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.